# Issue while Launching / Consuming a .NET Win-Forms EXE That Hosts WCF Service from .NET Windwos Service running as Local System

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

I am facing an issue right now in my application, below are few details around it.

High Level Design : Our SPA application talks to a Windows Service via Self-Hosted SignalR. This windows service runs as a Local System user on clients machines. This service other than communicating with certain scanners connected to client machine , is also responsible for installing a new version of the required components / update itself with new version (Kind of like windows updates). All components we are sending for update have to signed digitally. There is a logic built in this windows service that  validates signature of the downloaded packages with CERT Revocation list over internet using WinCert.dll.

Client Requirement : Few of our clients would now have Proxy configured on their client machines. Which is an issue for our windows service now  , as it is running under local system account , it can't reach to internet to download updates / validate against CERT revocation list. And if we try to retrieve proxy settings inside service we can't get those as proxy is configured for logged in user and not local system.

Design to Address Requirement : So what we are doing is , we are launching an EXE (using pinvoke like CreateProcessAsUser etc.) for logged in user from windows service. Inside this EXE we are retrieving proxy settings (now we can query coz EXE is launched as logged in user) and setting them at process level. Then we are hosting a Duplex WCF Service using named pipe / tcp binding inside EXE itself. Once EXE is started , proxy retrived and service is hosted , we are making requests from windows service to the WCF Service hosted inside EXE and raising callbacks to service from EXE.

Issue : The issue is that , we are not able to host WCF Service with TCP / Pipe binding inside EXE , when that EXE is launched from Windows Service. However if I launch that EXE manually from windows explorer by saying run as administrator , everything works fine. I am local administrator , so when I double click it / launch it from windows service for logged in user who is me, in task manager it shows me it is running as AUgane only , which is same when I say run as administrator. In both occasions it shows me I am launching exe for my user only.

For PIPE binding

1. When EXE is Launched from Windows service - It hosts the service , however when I try to communicate with it from service after my hosting is successfully (which I very in logs) , I am getting error "There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/ValidatorService/pipe1 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action".
2. When EXE is Launched from Windows Explorer as Administrator : When I do this I skip launch logic for EXE and make WCF calls  directly . Everything works in this scenario.

For TCP binding

1. When EXE is Launched from Windows service - It hosts the service , however when I try to communicate with it from service after my hosting is successfully (which I very in logs) , I am getting error "The service endpoint failed to listen on the URI net.tcp://localhost:9931/ValidatorService/' because access was denied.  Verify that the current user is granted access in the appropriate allowAccounts section of SMSvcHost.exe.config". Here it took all the suggestion provided in google and added my SID to SMSvcHost.exe.config to allowed accounts inside SMSvcHost.exe.config but that did not help.
2. When EXE is Launched from Windows Explorer as Administrator : When I do this I skip launch logic for EXE and make WCF calls  directly . Everything works in this scenario.

I think what I am seeing here is an obvious issue with launching code. As it is not able to launch EXE as an Administrator. I googled around a bit but suggestion offered were either tricky to implement or they are going to have me disable UAC , which is not possible when this app is distributed to thousands of clients.

I have attached here the code that I have wrote to launch the EXE , but it looks like something needs to be tweaked in this code to run the process as Administrator.

Please suggest if you guys have came across anything like this before. Also suggest if this idea is architecturally correct. If you get a chance to look at the attached launch code , and point out something obvious then that will be very helpful.

```
    public static bool LaunchUSCAsUser(bool visible)
    {
        IntPtr hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        var startInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
        var procInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        var pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
        int iResultOfCreateProcessAsUser;

        var bResult = true;
        var hImpersonationToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        var pSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

        //This gets us the session ID for whoever is logged into the pyshical console (local keyboard, mouse, monitor)
        uint activeSessionID = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

        if (activeSessionID == INVALID_SESSION_ID)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("LaunchProcessAsUser: WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId returned INVALID_SESSION_ID."));
        }

        //Now that we have the active session ID, we can do some checking
        Process currentProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        //If the current process is running in the same session as the one we want to launch
        //our new process in, there's really no point bothering with duplicating tokens, etc.
        if (activeSessionID != (uint)currentProc.SessionId)
        {
            uint Uresult = WTSQueryUserToken(activeSessionID, ref hImpersonationToken);

            if (Uresult != 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Convert the impersonation token to a primary token
                    bResult = DuplicateTokenEx(hImpersonationToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, IntPtr.Zero,
                        (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification, (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                        ref hUserToken);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseHandle(hImpersonationToken);
                }

                if (!bResult)
                {
                    uint errorCode = GetLastError();

                    //This error means the user does not have the priviledge needed to convert the token.
                    if (errorCode == 1314)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(String.Format("LaunchProcessAsUser: DuplicateTokenEx User does not have the needed priviledge for token duplication."));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception(String.Format("LaunchProcessAsUser: DuplicateTokenEx failed with error code: {0}", errorCode));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                uint errorCode = GetLastError();
                throw new Exception(String.Format("LaunchProcessAsUser: WTSQueryUserToken failed with error code: {0}", errorCode));
            }

            startInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STARTUPINFO));

            try
            {
                uint dwCreationFlags = CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | (uint)(visible ? CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE : CREATE_NO_WINDOW);
                startInfo.wShowWindow = (short)(visible ? SW.SW_SHOW : SW.SW_HIDE);
                startInfo.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";

                if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref pEnv, hUserToken, false))
                {
                    uint errorCode = GetLastError();
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("LaunchUserProcess: CreateEnvironmentBlock failed with error code: {0}", errorCode));
                }

                if (!CreateProcessAsUser(hUserToken,
                    ClientEXEFullPath, // Application Name
                    String.Empty, // Command Line Parameters
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    false,
                    dwCreationFlags,
                    pEnv,
                    WorkingDirectory, // Working directory
                    ref startInfo,
                    out procInfo))
                {
                    uint errorCode = GetLastError();
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("LaunchUserProcess: CreateProcessAsUser failed with error code: {0}", errorCode));
                }

                iResultOfCreateProcessAsUser = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hUserToken);
                if (pEnv != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    DestroyEnvironmentBlock(pEnv);
                }
                CloseHandle(procInfo.hThread);
                CloseHandle(procInfo.hProcess);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Since we're in the same session, just start the process the easy way.
            ProcessStartInfo PSInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ClientEXEFullPath, String.Empty);
            Process.Start(PSInfo);
        }

        return true;
    }
```